# how to convert a float value to rounded off in iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a float value i want to rounded off to nearest total i have find some math function but not working

Now potential profit is 300.52 so how to roundded of this please

```
     float potentialprofit=otherthanCereniaAnnual*totalProfit;
     NSString*potentialProfitTitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",potentialprofit];

[potentialProfit setTitle:potentialProfitTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: What do you want to round it off to?

Comment: i want that if number is 3.75 then it should become 4 and if it is 3.25 then it show 3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int result = (int)ceilf(myFloat );
int result = (int)roundf(myFloat );
int result = (int)floor(myFloat);

float result = ceilf(myFloat );
float result = roundf(myFloat );
float result = floor(myFloat);
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
float f = ...;
f = (int)(f+0.5);
```

if you want to handle negative value, try this:

```
f = (int)(f < 0 ? f-0.5 : f+0.5);
```