# How to round decimal for 2 decimal places in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

Let me know how to round decimal for 2 decimal places in Objective-C.

I would like to do like this.
(all of numbers following sentence is float value)

• round

10.118 => 10.12

10.114 => 10.11

• ceil

10.118 => 10.12

• floor

10.114 => 10.11

Thanks for checking my question.

Comment: You do it the same way that you do it in C :)

Comment: Do you need resulting values to be strings or remain floats?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749483/how-to-convert-a-float-value-to-rounded-off-in-iphone-app/10749620#10749620

Comment: If you work with primitives Anoop is the right answer, if you work with NSNumber object is a little different because you need to specify an NSNumberFormatter object. 
You can also use the NSDecimalRound function:

    void NSDecimalRound (
       NSDecimal *result,
       const NSDecimal *number,
       NSInteger scale,
       NSRoundingMode roundingMode
    );

NSDecimal is just an NSNumber subclass. I prefer the latter.

Comment: @Andrea NSDecimal is not a subclass of NSNumber. it is not even a class. NSDecimal is a C-struct. you are mixing them up with NSDecimalNumber.

Comment: @Andrea https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDecimal

Comment: You are totally right sorry for the mistake

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate of the given question; this one is about Objective-C, while the marked duplicate is only about C. Perhaps there is a cocoa library that is preferred over standard C libraries?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you actually need the number to be rounded, and not just when presenting it:

```
float roundToN(float num, int decimals)
{
    int tenpow = 1;
    for (; decimals; tenpow *= 10, decimals--);
    return round(tenpow * num) / tenpow;
}
```

Or always to two decimal places:

```
float roundToTwo(float num)
{
    return round(100 * num) / 100;
}
```

Comment: Um, this doesn't work for me. It gives me a float with six decimal places.

Comment: @TheJuicedWord: the correct NSLog/printf conversion specifier still needs to be `%.2f`, obviously.

Comment: @user529758 but that still doesn't address the fact that the actual `float` is _not_ properly rounded.

Comment: I would personally use roundf(100 * num) / 100 as I have had issues using round( )

Answer (score 17):

You can use the below code to format it to two decimal places

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits = 2;
formatter.setRoundingMode = NSNumberFormatterRoundUp;

NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(10.358)];
NSLog(@"Result %@",numberString); // Result 10.36
```

Comment: I think OP wants to *actually* round the number.

Comment: as per condition given by @Takuya (10.118 => 10.12

10.114 => 10.11

• ceil

10.118 => 10.12

• floor

10.114 => 10.11) i think this should work for him.

Comment: I mean, he doesn't want to *print* a rounded value but to *have* a rounded value.

Comment: Sorry i didnt get what u mean by "Print"/"To have"

Comment: Perhaps `.RoundUp` isn't the best rounding mode (e.g. it turns `10.351` to `10.36`); I'd recommend `.RoundHalfUp` (e.g. it turns `10.351` to `10.35`).

Comment: @user529758 this can easily be done with [`numberString.doubleValue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/doubleValue) or even [`[formatter numberFromString:numberString]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumberFormatter/numberFromString:)

Comment: NSNumberFormatter will convert "." into "," if your device region is selected differently like Brazil etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
float roundedFloat = (int)(sourceFloat * 100 + 0.5) / 100.0;
```

Comment: This isn't correct for negative numbers. There's a `round()` function in the C standard library.

Comment: True, but: 1. there were only positive numbers in the example, 2. my goal was just to show the idea ;)

Comment: I see your point, but this is not *the idea.* Sorry.